# What is the difference between a macrophage and dendritic cell?

Tags: homework, immune-system, eukaryotic-cells, mhc

I am aware that both these cells (monocytes) are phagocytes and are able to present antigens upon their own Class II - MHC integral proteins.

Other than their difference in structure (size and shape), what other differences do they have? For example, do they engage with T-Cells differently?

Answer (score -2):

[Macrophages can only activate the general T - Cells while dendritic cells can activate](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18560360/) memory T - cells as well. Also, dendritic cells don't survive after their effector function while macrophages do. [The main difference is the fact that dendritic cells present pathogens to T-cells while macrophages initiate the main](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S008525381553161X) response of removing the pathogen and then presenting their peptides to other cells.

This [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4594071/) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi Shadan. Thanks for answering. To improve your answer, please include credible references to support *specific* statements, otherwise the answer to such a rather specific question is suspect and will be downvoted. Scientifically, using phrases like "from what I know" and "I would say..." are unfortunately worse than unhelpful, they cast doubt or confusion, and take away from the link that you share at the end, which you may have quoted to answer the question very elegantly!